# PDOException could not find driver while running codeception test case in laravel 5.2 project in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, nginx, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04, codeception

```html
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\employees;
class PracticeTestCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }
    public function _after(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }
    public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
       $I->amOnPage('/login');
       $I->submitForm('form#login-email', ['email' => 'sekhar@gmail.com', 'password' => 'm12345']);
       $I->fillField('#login-email input[name=email]', 'sekhar@gmail.com');
       $I->fillField('#login-email input[name=password]', 'm12345');
       $I->click('LOGIN', '#btn-login');
       //$I->see('Welcome, Mani Rani','h4');
       $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/login?logincount=&email=sekhar%40gmail.com&password=m12345&button=');
    }
}


Here is my functional.suite.yml file:::: 
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
        - \Helper\Functional
```

PDOException could not find driver while running codeception test case in laravel 5.2 project in ubuntu.

**Here is my php -m output**:::
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: It would help if you added some code.

Comment: I've added code once check @moritzg

Comment: Did you enable the `pdo_mysql` module?

Comment: I'm new to nginx, Where is pdo_mysql module folder path in nginx @moritzg

Comment: What database connection your use in the `.env.testing`? And please paste the output of `php -m` from terminal in here so we can know if your module has been installed.

Comment: Added php -m output and DB connection in .env.testing @DharmaSaputra

Answer (score 0):

In your php modules list there are no mysql driver installed, you should install it. The driver needed when PHP PDO trying to connect to mysql server. To install it run:

`$ sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Don't forget to enable the extention in `php.ini` file find 

`;extension=php_pdo_mysql.so`

uncomment to 

`extension=php_pdo_mysql.so`

Save the file and restart the apache service

`service apache2 restart`

Hope it helps.

Comment: php-mysql is already the newest version - showing while installing.

Comment: I'm using nginx server, In `php5/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini` i've uncommented `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add suffix in PHP, then for install php5.6 or before add this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6   # for PHP 5.6
```

And install extensions by this command

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd php5.6-mysql php5.6-dom php5.6-cli
php5.6-json php5.6-common php5.6-mbstring php5.6-opcache
php5.6-readline
```

`